# Spark Data Frames On Huge Data Sets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to create a spark data frame on top of a mysql jdbc connection and save it to hive table. But was getting the gc overhead or timeout exceptions.

I did check the memory settings and changed them to max. The machine has 4Gb of virtual memory and the limits are set to 3GB.

The size of the table is 22Gb and I was creating partitions when loading so that the data will be divided between executors but that doesn't seem to be working.

Java Code:

```
import com.atrato.utils.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by dinesh on 11/24/16.
 */
public class ImportGsod {

    public void importTable(String jdbc, String driver, String sourceDBName, String sourceTableName, String destTableName, String user, String password, HiveContext hiveContext, SparkConf conf) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("*****************************************************");
        Connection connection = GetConnection.getConnection(jdbc,driver,sourceDBName,user,password);

        int executorMemory = GetExecutorMemory.getExecutorMemory(conf);
        System.out.println("Detected Executor Memory (In MB) :"+executorMemory);

//        int rowCount = GetRowCount.getRowCount(connection,sourceTableName);
        int rowCount = 114420316;
        System.out.println("Detected Row Count In Table      :"+rowCount);

        int rowSize = GetJavaRowSize.getJavaRowSize(connection,sourceTableName);
        System.out.println("Detected Row Size In Table       :"+rowSize);

        int memoryMaxRows = (int)(executorMemory/2);
        memoryMaxRows = (memoryMaxRows*1024*1024)/rowSize;
        System.out.println("Max Rows Per Executor            :"+memoryMaxRows);

        int numOfPartitions = rowCount/memoryMaxRows+1;
        System.out.println("Number Of Partitions             :"+numOfPartitions);

//        String minDistinct = GetMinDistinct.getMinDistinct(connection,sourceTableName);
        String minDistinct = "month";
        System.out.println("Detected Min Distinct Columns    :"+minDistinct);

        System.out.println("*****************************************************");


        Map<String, String> conn = new HashMap<>();
        conn.put("url",jdbc);
        conn.put("dbtable",sourceDBName+"."+sourceTableName);
        conn.put("driver",driver);
        conn.put("user",user);
        conn.put("password",password);
        conn.put("partitionColumn",minDistinct);
        conn.put("lowerBound","0");
        conn.put("upperBound",memoryMaxRows+"");
        conn.put("numPartitions","12");

        DataFrame sourceTable = hiveContext.read().format("jdbc").options(conn).load();


        Map<String ,String > columnTypes = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String ,Column> newColumns = new HashMap<>();

        StructType columns = sourceTable.schema();

        StructField[] columnMeta = columns.fields();

        for(StructField column : columnMeta) {
            String dataType = column.dataType().toString();
            columnTypes.put(column.name(), dataType.substring(0,dataType.length()-4).toLowerCase());
        }

        columnTypes.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals("date")).forEach(entry -> {
            Column column = sourceTable.col(entry.getKey()).cast("string");
            newColumns.put(entry.getKey(), column);
        });

        DataFrame destTable = sourceTable;

        for(Map.Entry<String,Column> columnEntry :newColumns.entrySet()){
            destTable = destTable.withColumn(columnEntry.getKey(),columnEntry.getValue());
        }
        destTable.write().mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(destTableName);
    }
}
```

HDFS Config:
core-site.xml :

```
<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.com    press.Lz4Codec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>simple</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.rpc.protection</name>
    <value>authentication</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.ssl.require.client.cert</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.ssl.keystores.factory.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.ssl.FileBasedKeyStoresFactory</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.ssl.server.conf</name>
    <value>ssl-server.xml</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.ssl.client.conf</name>
    <value>ssl-client.xml</value>
    <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
    <value>DEFAULT</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.mapred.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.mapred.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.flume.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.flume.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.HTTP.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.HTTP.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.yarn.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.yarn.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.instrumentation.requires.admin</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:8022</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:50470</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.port</name>
    <value>50470</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:50070</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>134217728</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.permissions.umask-mode</name>
    <value>022</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.acls.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/var/run/hdfs-sockets/dn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.skip.checksum</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.domain.socket.data.traffic</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.admin.acl</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:8032</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:8033</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:8030</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:8031</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:8088</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.https.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:8090</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2816</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.amliveliness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
    <value>1000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.am.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.container.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.nm.liveness-monitor.interval-ms</name>
    <value>1000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nm.liveness-monitor.expiry-interval-ms</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.client.thread-count</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
    <value>$HADOOP_CLIENT_CONF_DIR,$HADOOP_CONF_DIR,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.user-as-default-queue</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.sizebasedweight</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.fair.assignmultiple</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.max-completed-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/logs</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix</name>
    <value>logs</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml:

```
<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize</name>
    <value>10000000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.counters.max</name>
    <value>120</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.counters.groups.max</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type</name>
    <value>BLOCK</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zlib.compress.level</name>
    <value>DEFAULT_COMPRESSION</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor</name>
    <value>64</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent</name>
    <value>0.8</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies</name>
    <value>10</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.timeout</name>
    <value>600000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb</name>
    <value>16</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.speculative</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.speculative</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps</name>
    <value>0.8</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:10020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:19888</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.https.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:19890</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.admin.address</name>
    <value>quickstart.cloudera:10033</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.staging-dir</name>
    <value>/user</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.am.max-attempts</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>128</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.ubertask.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx52428800</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx52428800</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx52428800</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.admin.user.env</name>
    <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.heap.memory-mb.ratio</name>
    <value>0.8</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
    <value>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,$MR2_CLASSPATH</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
    <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

hadoop-env.sh :

```
# Prepend/Append plugin parcel classpaths

if [ "$HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST" = 'true' ]; then
  # HADOOP_CLASSPATH={{HADOOP_CLASSPATH_APPEND}}
  :
else
  # HADOOP_CLASSPATH={{HADOOP_CLASSPATH}}
  :
fi
# JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH={{JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH}}

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$( ([[ ! '{{CDH_MR2_HOME}}' =~ CDH_MR2_HOME ]] && echo {{CDH_MR2_HOME}} ) || echo ${CDH_MR2_HOME:-/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/}  )
export YARN_OPTS="-Xmx3221225472 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true $YARN_OPTS"
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

I was trying to do the partitions so that spark wont load all the data into memory at the same time. But that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks and do let me know if you need any more info.

Link to the data that I'm trying to load : 
https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:samples.gsod

Comment: Ehm, I'm afraid your approach here is completely off. You need to obtain a better understanding of Spark before trying to tackle this problem, so for now I will simply recommend that you go through a couple of tutorials and read a bit about Spark.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you actually point me to some documentation which describes how data frames are handled from a memory perspective. I could only find docs on how to write a data frame and its details about its api.  @GlennieHellesSindholt